# why is VQ-VAE considered a variational encoder?

Tags: autoencoders, variational-inference

I'm reading about [VQ-VAE](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/file/7a98af17e63a0ac09ce2e96d03992fbc-Paper.pdf) and I'm not sure why do they say we can view it as a [VAE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.02691.pdf). Can you explicitly show:

- what is the latent z-space - is it the discrete space where z can take the integers 1..K where K is the number of embedding vectors?
- what is the true posterior p(z|x)? is it indeed intractable to use for calculating the marginal p(x), if we are dealing just in a scalar that can hold integers 1..K where K is a moderate 128?
- why do we need to sample from z's distribution in VAE while in VQ-VAE we just take a deterministic distribution and just use the closest embedding to the encoder output?
- can you show the ELBO formulation, and show how it boils down to only $log p(x|z_q(x))$?

Comment: The z-space is probably the space where the vectors live, rather than where their indices 1..K live.

Comment: There are situations/variants where you don't need to sample in the VAE, but simply take the mean. For example when you use a trained VAE for dimensionality reduction.